# 100% Code Coverage; Unit Tests for Data Class Models

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

Code coverage seems to be a hot topic these days. And managers are starting to refuse anything less than 100% coverage (yikes!). My question is, how do you test data classes? For me, back in the good Java days, testing DTOs, POJOs, and models with getters/setters were pretty pointless. But now this seems to be the requirement, so I am wondering if there are new testing techniques that I do not know about.

```
internal data class RegisterUserRequestDto(
        @SerializedName("email") val email: String?,
        @SerializedName("password") val password: String?,
        @SerializedName("phoneNumber") val phoneNumber: String?
)
```

Anyone with ideas?

Comment: What about testing The code using the data classes? Shouldn’t that cover the data class?

Comment: @NathanHughes Yep! I have those tests. But that still shows up as 0% on jacoco. There is no logic to these model classes. I am just wondering if there is some sort of model testing pattern or technique I am not familiar with that developers are using.

Comment: Imo, what your managers ask you is pointless since you're only adding new tests to gain coverage. Once you'll reach 100%, you'll just move on to another low-coverage area, without asking yourself is the test you wrote is relevant and exhaustive. To me coverage is a metric that os badly used and often false-positive.

Comment: As you said, testing getters and setters is pointless and it's still is. But now managers want something to report to the client and it's usually test coverage or sonar analysis. I think that you should explain to your manager that coverage only shows where tests are missing, it's not an indicator of well tested coe.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Great response! I appreciate these words. You and I think alike. I agree with you. And I have spoken to the managers and explained exactly this, but they aren't budging. So I am doing my best to accommodate. I think what Bill K posted below could work. But as you said, I am just moving from one low coverage area to the next just to get the coverage. It's no longer about facility, utility, function or logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a class is used reflectively, it can be tested reflectively.  For the class you listed, you simply have to ensure that it has email, password and phoneNumber fields that can be read and written as strings.

This could be done in a single call to a reflective method that took a class and 3 method names as parameters.  It could even validate the annotation's existence and value against an external reference (A database schema?  An xml interface description file?) if required which could prove to be quite useful.

Comment: Excellent! This is the kind of thing I was wondering about. Great response. I will do exactly that. Thanks!

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I didn't mention--if you had an external reference (such as an xml interface description) you could actually drive the entire test from that specification and not have any code specifically testing a given object.  Updating the spec would immediately cause your tests to fail because the your code no longer matches the spec.

Comment: Good callout! I understand what you mean.